# Grab route from other site

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-maps

Is it possible somehow grab route from others maps and use in my personal map?

For example how to grab map from this [ultimatedrives](https://www.ultimatedrives.net/top-10-roads/details.php?route_ID=100005) site?

Comment: you will need URL which will have route encoded in coordinates like `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/50.8334517,20.5185821/Le%C5%9Bna,+26-060+Ch%C4%99ciny,+Po%C4%BEsko/@50.8311354,20.5242208,13.71z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x47178659f37bd24f:0xf8cdf780bcab2f70!2m2!1d20.5023887!2d50.8254675`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- go to **[https://www.ultimatedrives.net/](https://www.ultimatedrives.net/top-10-roads/details.php?route_ID=100005)** site
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>I</kbd>** (on chrome)
- and then **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>F</kbd>**
- type **google.maps.LatLng**
- copy paste coordinates into **https://www.google.com/maps/**
- press search icon and drag blue route to adjust it
- done

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]